# Use 'Contains' in better exposed filters?

Tags: 7, views

I have a taxonomy of Office departments that I am using to filter my contacts which are brought into drupal with Ldap to search people by department. Some contacts have more info in their dept field when brought in from Ldap. 
For example 'Credit - London' instead of just credit. Is the a way to filter by contains 'Credit'? 
There are no options on the expose filter [image: expose filter options]

Answer (score 0):

If you use the field as textfield, then you will have options to filters department like above.

Comment: I would like to be able to use a filter with checkboxs . I think using the field as a textfield means I won't able to do that?! I'll just have an input box